# How to use prepopulated_field with email without omitting special characters in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to prepopulate username with email in django admin but it escapes '@' and '.'

Admin.py

```py
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreateForm
    prepopulated_fields = {'username': ('email',)}
    inlines = [SitePermissionInline]
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email','username', 'password1', 'password2', ),
        }),
    )
```

In admin form if email is test@test.com, username returns testtestcom.

I want username to prepopulate the email as it is i.e username - test@test.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractBaseUser` model doesn't allow those characters in the username field:

> clean()
>
> Normalizes the username by calling normalize_username(). If you override this method, be sure to call super() to retain the normalization

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.clean)

What you can do if you want to use emails instead of usernames for auth is to 1/ ensure your User model's `email` field has a unique constraint, then 2/ write a custom auth backend that can uses the email field instead of the username (which takes about a dozen lines of code or so).

EDIT:

> I want to use either email or username because I have different apps that require either email or username

Then your auth backend could look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

class EmailOrUsernameBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()

        try: 
            users = UserModel.objects.filter(
                Q(username__iexact=username) |
                Q(email__iexact=username)
            ).distinct()
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if users.exists():
            user = users.first()
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        return None
```

You of course still have to ensure emails are unique... this can be done with a custom user model with a proper unicity constraint on the email field.

Comment: I want to use either email or username because I have different apps that require either email or username

Comment: Thank you. That has solved my problem @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: But the filter query should have
```python
     user = UserModel.objects.filter(
                Q(username__iexact=username) |
                Q(email__iexact=email)
            ).distinct()
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: This example backend was defined to let the user type either a username or email in the authform's 'username' field. But you can indeed add an  "email" argument too and change the query accordingly - the point of custom auth backend is to allow you to make them work as you want ;-)

Comment: NB: make sure you read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/